# Mysql Join prevent merge same name column from two tables

Tags: mysql

I use something like this select to join table:

```
SELECT p.*, g.id, g.hold FROM pictures AS p 
 INNER JOIN galleries as g ON g.id = p.gallery_id
WHERE p.views > $views AND g.hold <> 1
```

As a result I got `ID` from second table `g`, but I expect it from `p`. So, `ID` replaced by `g.id` and contain two same value colums with different names (ID and GALLERY_ID)

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 35 <- same as GALLERY ID?... :( must be p.ID
        [GALLERY_ID] => 35
        [HOLD] => 0
    )
```

array creating:

```
while( ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) )
    $arr_db_rows[] = $row;
```

Comment: Use an alias for g.id - "g.id as gallery_id" - although I cannot understand why you need the same info twice!?! In fact, I'm not sure how you knew which `id` the value came from!?!

Comment: I see you have p.* (which will give you p.id) as well as g.id both in the select list so you will get both. Not sure how you are populating the array so can't tell why its gallery_id and not p.id.

Comment: It is better to give query output and expected output here as it is not clear like this that how you are getting values in Array.

Comment: Strawberry, I check my table and found the values. I will try alias as you suggested, but not sure about "same info twice".. where?.. Adarsha Shah, I added function that create array for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-> Instead of 'SELECT p.*' and add columns of 'p' using 'p.column_name'. Avoid 'p.gallary_id'.
-> Or, just remove 'g.id' from 'SELECT' column names, and you will only have gallary_id column. You can still use 'g.id' in the 'where' clause.

Comment: removing `g.id, g.hold` from select and live `p.*` helps. thanks